# what are the other usage of word “been” in english?

Tags: grammar, tense, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

I have heard usage of "been" other that in perfect continuous tense.

like when we are talking about past, could we say that "I been given some work"?

Is the above sentence correct? if not why?

But, this sentence convince me, because it is the situation in which I am talking about past and some thing happened on me, so in order to say that I need to use forms of "be", but I cannot say in perfect form because "have " and "had" is not form of "be", but if I use "have been" or "had been" then it will be in perfect continuous, again I don't want to add continuous sense to it, it should be in perfect with 3rd form of verb.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that sentence is absolutely incorrect. Grammatically, you should follow the pattern ***to have been [past participle]***. If the action took place before some reference point in the past, use the past perfect tense: ***I had been given some work to do***. If the action took place in the past but with a connection to the present moment, use the present perfect tense: ***I have been given some work to do***. There's no ifs or buts. That's how English grammar works.

However, if you start watching a lot of American movies, one day you will hear someone say ***I done it!*** or something to that effect. That's actually incorrect and the only time you'll ever hear this said is from a country person or a street tough using nonstandard English grammar.

If you insist on using a past form of the *to be* verb, use ***was***:

> I was given some work to do.

Comment: is the sentence " he is gone" is correct?

Comment: Yes, that sentence is correct.

Comment: what is 3rd form of "be"?

Comment: You mean the "3rd person form" of the verb ***to be***? That would be ***is*** for singular objects and ***are*** for plural ones. That's for the present tense. ***was*** (singular) and ***were*** (plural) for the past tense.

Comment: then which form "been" is of "be"?

Comment: ***been*** is the past particle of ***to be***. You use past participles either as part of perfect tenses or as adjectives or as part of passive voice constructions and also in some other situations. Use of past participles is actually quite a big topic on its own.

Comment: In current English, "He is gone" is grammatical, but "gone" is an adjective. In early Modern English (2-4 hundred years ago) "he is gone" was a grammatical verb form, equivalent to "he has gone": this is still sometimes used for effect, as a deliberate archaism. You can see the difference when you put a destination: "He is gone home" or "He is gone to London" are archaic in current English.

Comment: *I done it* is not wrong in the situations in which it is said. For example: *We done now?* is fine in informal English. Also, *I been given some work* and *I done been given some work* are correct in certain dialects. To say any of these is incorrect, you should stipulate that you're talking about the dialect called standard English.

Comment: My experience is that many people saying "I been" simply swallow the "ve" rather than omitting it altogether.